# Python using pandas search entry just in the first column return values of entire row

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and have trouble figuring pandas out. I tried the whole evening but couldn't get it to work. This is probably a duplicate question, however I searched for it and still didn't solve it.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Programming\Pipeline\Tests\vfxdatasheet.csv')
df2 = df.columns.get_values()
print (df2)
```

gets me my columns. So far so good.
I want to effeciently search for an entry just in the first column called "Shot#". If the entry is found return the information of it's entire row (as a list or whatever)

And bonus point: how do I return a value found in a specific row / column

[This is my data table which I export as a utf-8 encoded csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jglhk.png)

Thanks for helping a total noob. :)

EDIT:

```
shotid = '001_0010'
ix = df['Shot#'].loc[df['Shot#'].str.contains(shotid)].index
print (ix)
```

Results in a key error I got yesterday the whole time. I am using WinPython, is there a problem with the pandas package maybe?

**EDIT 2:** Ok, I know why it wouldn't work. I didn't set the seperator when creating the data frame. Stupid mistake!

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Programming\Pipeline\Tests\vfxdatasheet.csv", sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Programming/Pipeline/Python/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    ix = df['Shot#'].loc[df['Shot#'].str.contains(shotid)].index
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Shot#'
```

Comment: What have you tried? You write that you tried the whole evening - how are you looking for the value? How do you plan to know the index of its row when found? How will you write out the corresponding row given an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Shot#': ['001_0010','002_0020','003_0010','003_0020','003_0030','004_0010','003_0010'],
                   'play': ['a','b','c','d','a','b','d']})

# let's say
val_to_search = '003_0010'

# get row index value where match is found
ix = df['Shot#'].loc[df['Shot#'].str.contains(val_to_search)].index

# get rows of match value as output
df.values[ix]

# output
array([['003_0010', 'c'],
       ['003_0010', 'd']], dtype=object)
```

If you want to return a value from specfic column, there are multiple methods to do that:

**Method 1:**

```
df.apply(lambda row: row['Shot#'] if row['Shot#'] == val_to_search else np.nan, axis=1)
```

**Method 2:**

```
mask = df['Shot#'].str.contains(val_to_search)
df['new_col'] = df.loc[mask,'Shot#']

print(df)

    Shot#    play   new_col
0   001_0010    a   NaN
1   002_0020    b   NaN
2   003_0010    c   003_0010
3   003_0020    d   NaN
4   003_0030    a   NaN
5   004_0010    b   NaN
6   003_0010    d   003_0010
```

Comment: Thank you so far, I edited my first post with the key error I get all the time. Any idea?

Comment: I just didn't set the csv seperator correctly, sorry and thank you.